# How does Python import really work? In a chain of import

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, path, sys.path

**Hi fellow Pythonista,**

While I have been coding with Python for quite some time now, recently I found my some problem in my understanding of python's import mechanism.

I am hoping you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance. Your help is much appreciated.

#### Setup

```
myprogram
 ┠━run.py
 ┗━mypackage                   
     ┠━ __init__.py 
     ┠━ foo.py
     ┗━ bar.py
```

The content of the python files are as follow:

```
# run.py
import sys
print sys.path
from mypackage import foo

# foo.py
import sys
print sys.path
import bar

# bar.py
import sys
print sys.path
```

Neither `myprogram` nor any of its sub directories is in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

#### My Current Understanding

The flow of execute:

1. Start running `run.py`. The path to the containing directory, `PATH/myprogram` is added to the `sys.path`.
2. Executing the statement `from mypackage import foo`. Since we now have `PATH/myprogram` in the `sys.path`, the interpreter can find the `mypackage` and then locate the `foo.py` without problem.
3. Start running `foo.py`, the interpreter adds the path to the containing directory `PATH/myprogram/mypackage` to the `sys.path`.
4. At this point, both `PATH/myprogram` and `PATH/myprogram/mypackage` is included in `sys.path`.
5. Executing the statement `import bar`. Since we have `PATH/myprogram/mypackage` added to the `sys.path`, the import statement can execute successfully without problem.

#### Question

After running the `run.py`, I discover all of the `print sys.path` statements yield the same outputs. All of them contains `PATH/myprogram` but not `PATH\myprogram\mypackage`, which contradicts to my understanding above.

It seems the home directory path is only added for the script that initialised the process.But if that is the case, then how is the `import bar` statement in `foo.py` execute successful if `PATH\myprogram\mypackage` is not in the search path?

BTW, I am using python 2.7 on a MAC OS X machine.

Comment: to find out how it works, see  ["Modules and Packages" (3 hours) talk by David Beazley at PyCon 2015](http://pyvideo.org/video/3387/modules-and-packages-live-and-let-die)

Answer (score 0):

sys.path is not a place to add anything by python itself.

The paths are added to modules cache, docs are clear about that: https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#import

Print out the `sys.modules` and `sys.path_importer_cache` to get the overview. The cache has the path to run.py and it can find other modules starting from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried printing out `sys.path_import_cache`, and I do see the `PATH/myprogram/mypackage` show up.  But I still don't understand how the interpreter find the `bar` module. Or how does the `finder objects`'s `find_module()` actually search for the module.

Comment: Almost all of the sources suggest that if the module is not on the `sys.path` it will not get imported. In my example, it is clearly not the case. So I am still confused.

Comment: sys.path is used to manually add paths that are out of scope of python interpreter. The other option is to use PYTHONPATH bash variable. Both methods will add a folder to python "module finder" but checking sys.path is the last on the python interest list. Before that it look in it's internal caches (that are faster). 

So your sources are right - if you want to import something that is not imported to your current interpreter - you have to add it to sys.path (like you want new module from totally different path). In other circumstances it's not necessary.